# Mock a Django Model method

Tags: python, django, mocking

I am trying to mock a method in a different file, but am unsure of what I am doing wrong.

```
#a.py
@patch("b.Trigger.is_valid_trigger")
def true(*args,**kwargs):
    return True


class TriggerTest(AsyncTestCase):

    async def test_apply_working(self):
       await b.Trigger().is_valid_trigger()
```

```
#b.py 
class Trigger(Module):
    async def is_valid_trigger(self, event):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

However, still a NotImplementedError is raised.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
from unittest.mock import patch

from aiounittest import AsyncTestCase

from . import b


def true(*args, **kwargs):
    return True


class TriggerTest(AsyncTestCase):

    @patch("<PACKAGE_NAME>.b.Trigger.is_valid_trigger", true)
    async def test_apply_working(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args, **kwargs)
        await b.Trigger().is_valid_trigger(None)
```

Note that `a.py` and `b.py` should be in the same package and package name should be inserted at `<PACKAGE_NAME>`

Comment: Because of patch the async method is never called